# Is Trigamma function integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, gamma-function

The question stems from when I derive the jeffreys prior for a gamma distribution, and the resulting prior is(proportional to) the square root of the trigamma function. I'm wondering if it's a proper distribution, aka is trigamma integrable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. The trigamma function is the derivative of the digamma function. So the the integral of it is the digamma function.